# How should I apply this function to the strings of a list given this situation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, request, list-comprehension

How can I apply the above function to each string of this list?:

```
lis = ['hi how are you',
 'pretty good',
 'the quick brown fox',
 'the is quick brown fox play',
 'play the quick brown fox']
```

I tried to:

```
[ request(x) for x in lis ]
```

I also tried to map over the elements of the list and it did not worked.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your given code has several undefined variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem lies in your global variable, **lis_**.  You manipulate this through all of the **lis** entries.  You return the list reference for *each* element of your comprehension, but continue to update the list on later parsing.

What you get is a list of identical pointers (each one is the reference to **lis_**), each of which contains all of the processing.

To fix this, use proper encapsulated programming practices.  Use local variables, clean them on each call, and return only the value needed in the calling program.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: when I do `request('hi how are you')` I get: `[('hi', 'hi', 'LN-'), ('how', 'how', 'ERMPN7'), ('are', 'be', 'VI-P1PSA-N-N9'), ('you', 'you', 'PP-S2AN8')]`, I think the issue is the request.

Comment: Could you show how to: "use proper encapsulated programming practices. Use local variables, clean them on each call, and return only the value needed in the calling program." given this situation?...

Comment: @J.Do: no, I can't.  Modular programming is a concept, not something to show in a simple example.  Applying it to the code that you've now removed would have required a major rewrite.  One part of it is that *all* communication between a function and the calling program happens through the call itself: the call arguments and the return value.  Use no global variables, create no hidden side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be helpful?

```
lis = ['hi how are you',
       'pretty good',
       'the quick brown fox',
       'the is quick brown fox play',
       'play the quick brown fox']


def requ(text):
    # This mimics the request
    output = []
    for word in text.split():
        # This just mimics getting some ID for each word
        xyz = "".join(str([ord(x) for x in word])).replace(", ", "")
        # This mimics the word root part
        if word in ["are", "is"]:
            output.append((word, "be", xyz))
        else:
            output.append((word, word, xyz))
    return output


new_lis = [requ(w) for w in lis]

print(new_lis)
```

Output:

```
[[('hi', 'hi', '[104105]'), ('how', 'how', '[104111119]'), ('are', 'be', '[97114101]'), ('you', 'you', '[121111117]')], [('pretty', 'pretty', '[112114101116116121]'), ('good', 'good', '[103111111100]')], [('the', 'the', '[116104101]'), ('quick', 'quick', '[11311710599107]'), ('brown', 'brown', '[98114111119110]'), ('fox', 'fox', '[102111120]')], [('the', 'the', '[116104101]'), ('is', 'be', '[105115]'), ('quick', 'quick', '[11311710599107]'), ('brown', 'brown', '[98114111119110]'), ('fox', 'fox', '[102111120]'), ('play', 'play', '[11210897121]')], [('play', 'play', '[11210897121]'), ('the', 'the', '[116104101]'), ('quick', 'quick', '[11311710599107]'), ('brown', 'brown', '[98114111119110]'), ('fox', 'fox', '[102111120]')]]
```

Comment: One second, I see you are making requests for each string (sentence).

Comment: I guess is the api request... is there a way of cleaning each request after making another one?.

Comment: Hm, not the best solution, but you could also attempt to fix things afterwards.

Comment: Well finally I solved it splitting everything in more functions... I do not understand why splitting the above procedure in more functions worked out.

Comment: That is what I and the other posters would have recommended, otherwise you would have to fix the results e.g. like [this](http://pastebin.com/RqEp7gzM) which is only a poor substitute for approaching it correctly from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension is fine, the reason you get strange output looks to be that the request function always returns a reference to the global variable lis_, which you keep appending things to. You should create lis_ as a local variable inside convert().